# How to choose where Urllib saves an image?

Tags: python, selenium, urllib

I am using selenium and urllib to download images, and as of now, urllib just saves into the folder where the python script is. Is there a way to change where the images are saved?

```
url2 = url.get_attribute("src")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url2, abbr2 + ".jpg")
```

thank you!

Comment: `where = r"C:\somewhere"; os.path.join(where, abbr2 + ".jpg")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a directory path as part of the filename. You can supply an absolute path or a relative path. E.g., to save it in the parent folder, you would provide `"../" + abbr2 + ".jpg"`